# Unable to complete 'Trouble In Skyrim' radiant quest set in Falkreath Watchtower

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been given a quest by the Companions to kill the Warlocks of 'Crossroads Watchtower' AKA 'Falkreath Watchtower' for the quest 'Trouble In Skyrim'. However I already cleared this tower pre-quest and now when I go to the tower, the quest target just hovers over the area where the enemy, a necromancer, should be. How can I fix this bug using console commands, keeping in mind that there is no body for the main NPC of this location? Also if it helps, the NPC he resurrects to fight is a glitchy ash pile where directly aiming at it and pressing <kbd>E</kbd> achieves nothing, meaning I have to move the mouse until I discover "another" ash pile for the same NPC.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the area, waiting 30+ days so it resets, and returning?

Answer (score 1):

The quest ID for [Trouble in Skyrim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Trouble_in_Skyrim) is: CR05

Try this command:

> setstage CR05 20